# How to preg_split() on non-letter/non-dash?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to split on characters that are neither `\p{L}` nor the `-`. I am a bit confused. `\P{L}|[^-]` will obviously not work as everything will match `[^-]`. I do not know how to put a Unicode class inside `[]`. Lookahead / lookbehind will latch on the previous / following character.

In other words, I need to split `foo-bar;dásh` into `['foo-bar', 'dásh']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for both:

```
$res = preg_split('/[^\pL-]+/u', $str);
```

This will split on `+` *one or more* characters that are neither an [unicode letter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) `\pL` nor a dash `-`

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zG5kW1/1), [eval.in](https://eval.in/422391)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually split on:

```
/[^\p{L}-]/u
```

Which will match any character that is not a unicode letter and not a dash.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM1gL1/3)

Comment: Huh! http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php doesn't even mention the word Unicode.

Comment: And that page doesn't mention character classes... I [added](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/en/trunk/reference/pcre/pattern.syntax.xml?annotate=337628&pathrev=337628#l1274) it to the character classes page for now, we can document on the Unicode page if we want to.